# VLC IMDB extension & plugin?

Tags: vlc, plugins

Does this plugin do anything ? ... https://addons.videolan.org/p/1153989/

I've copied it to as many vlc extensions folders as I could find all with either no result or it doesn't do anything. I've only been using Ubuntu for a week so am completely clueless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular plugin can be added to vlc and set running but it is very old with a copyright date of 2010 and does *not* work as advertised.

However you can try it out by copying the downloaded lua file `140695-imdb.lua` to the correct location of `~/.local/share/vlc/lua/extensions/140695-imdb.lua`. You may have to create this file structure *manually* by running the following command from a Terminal window:

```
mkdir -pv ~/.local/share/vlc/lua/extensions/
```

Then the plugin is activated by accessing 'View --> The Internet Movie Database' as seen in my screenshot below:

[image]

But this plugin is old and does not appear to work as advertised, the IMDB search link did not manage to appropriately find movie information in my testing...

Comment: Ok thanks. I've ended up using tinyMediaManager to get meta info.